# Parse doesn't send push from android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Since few days I'm fighting with problem of not sending pushes from Android.

Here is my code:

```
 ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setChannel("ch" + GlobalData.sUserSend.getObjectId());

    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    try {
        data.put("alert", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() + " has sent you gesture!");
        data.put("badge", "1");
        data.put("sound", "default");
        data.put("user_id", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    push.setData(data);

    push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (mLoadingDialogFragment != null) {
                mLoadingDialogFragment.dismiss();
            }

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(SendGestureActivity.this, ConversationActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

iOS version of this application is working fine. I can receive pushes on android and iOS. When I check in parse console (Push tab) there are only pushes sent from iOS. ParseException in callback is null. I'm using Parse 1.9.0 and it's quite possible that since update that stoped working. Any solutions?

EDIT: in android logcat I have this:
04-08 19:28:09.299    1093-1797/pl.essentialapps.five V/com.parse.ParseRequest﹕ Request failed. Waiting 3028 milliseconds before attempt #2
04-08 19:28:12.549    1093-1890/pl.essentialapps.five V/com.parse.ParseRequest﹕ Request failed. Waiting 6056 milliseconds before attempt #3
04-08 19:28:18.834    1093-2116/pl.essentialapps.five V/com.parse.ParseRequest﹕ Request failed. Waiting 12112 milliseconds before attempt #4
04-08 19:28:31.164    1093-2230/pl.essentialapps.five V/com.parse.ParseRequest﹕ Request failed. Giving up.

EDIT2:
I've tried in several ways send push:

- addChannel (as above) - fail
- installation query with whereContains my channel - fail
- installation query - firstly quering user by id, next installation by user - working
- addChannels - arraylist with one item - string with my channel name - fail

so looks like channels are not working, but I have them set correctly. Every installation has: ["global","chagk0Mgz3LQ"] - the second is "ch"+user_id